# Python: Formatting a string with a variable that must be inside curly braces {}

Tags: python, regex

My task is to make a function with regex that returns the matches that are `count` word characters long or longer.

Here's what I tried:

```
import re

# EXAMPLE:
# >>> find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me")
# ['baby', 'balloon']

def find_words(count, a_string):
    pattern = r'\w{{{},}}'.format(count)
    return re.findall(pattern, a_string)
```

The reason for the mess of curly braces is that I am attempting to [escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1875706/4063844).

The final search string (`pattern`) that I want would be something like `\w{`***`count`***`,}`

EDIT: Forgot the `return` statement in my original post. I'll leave this here because the answers coming in are actually valuable.

Comment: `return re.findall(pattern, a_string)`. Attention is important :)

Comment: Oops... I'm going to bed now

Comment: Use: ``"{{{0:s}}}".format("4")`` for example.

Comment: @PM2Ring You can use double braces as well

Comment: @Travis: Sorry, I got confused. You need to use backslash to escape braces in a regex, but doubling the braces escapes them for the `format` function.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [`%`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) operator?

```
In [1]: def find_words(count, a_string):
   ...:     pattern = r'\w{%s,}' % count
   ...:     return re.findall(pattern, a_string)

In [2]: find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me")
Out[2]: ['baby', 'balloon']
```